# JProfiler - Application profiling

Tags: jprofiler

I have installed JProfiler 8.1.1 on windows machine. But 
under Session -> Start Center -> Quick Attach of JProfiler GUI client no JVM is listed. But I can see java 1.8 is installed in my machine.
I can see warning on JProfiler GUI client saying "Attach functionality is broken in your system". I am new to using JProfiler. Can anybody please help?.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the attach functionality. You can add a VM parameter to the profiled JVM. To get the details, invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

in the JProfiler GUI.